# How can I install tkinter for both python 3.4 and python 3.5?

Tags: software-installation, python, tkinter

How can I install tkinter for both python 3.4 and python 3.5?

Currently, tkinter is installed for python 3.4 (i.e., `import tkinter` runs fine in the python 3.4 interpreter). However I don't know how to install tkinter for python 3.5.

`sudo apt-get install python3-tk` doesn't work: it says `python3-tk` is already installed (which is unsurprising since it is installed for python 3.4).

I use Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

---

python3.4:

```
jh@gr:/scratch/test$ python3.4
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
>>>
```

python3.5:

```
jh@gr:/scratch/test$ python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jul 17 2016, 00:00:00)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')
ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

As a side note, restinstalling the package `python3-tk` doesn't change the situation (i.e., afterward tkinter works in python 3.4 and not in python 3.5):

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-tk
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk
```

Comment: How to install it in redhat?

Answer (score 1):

Check the libpython packages you have installed, and if missing, install libpython3.5-stdlib.

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.5-stdlib
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I already have this package `ibpython3.5-stdlib is already the newest version.`